# Android GCM PushNotification - Add add custom sound file in app

Tags: android, push-notification, uri, google-cloud-messaging

I am getting GCM Push Notification successfully. Now i want to add custom sound file instead of default sound. I have tried with **Uri** from

> file:///res/raw/pop.mp3

in

> Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

but not success. Please share if you have better solution.

My **GCMIntentService.java** method code is below -

```
/**
 * Issues a notification to inform the user that server has sent a message.
 */
private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {

    System.out.println("Called generateNotification>>>>>>>>>>>>>"+message);
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    // Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);

    String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_icon)
            .setContentTitle(title)

            .setStyle(
                    new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message))
            .setContentText(message);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context,
            SplashActivity.class);
    PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(intent);

    Notification notification = mBuilder.build();
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;


    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);



}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To add custom sound add this

```
notification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.pop);
```

i.e. In your code change

```
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
```

to

```
notification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" +R.raw.pop);
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
```