# How to make push notification with specific sound?

Tags: android, audio, notifications

I'm working on android app with system of notifications and i need the android device to push the notification with a specific sound i stored on assets folder
this is my java code for notification :

```
Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(MainActivity.this)
    .setTicker("Calcupital")
    .setContentTitle("Calcupital")
    .setContentText("User Information has been updated successfully")
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.login)
    .setContentIntent(pIntent).getNotification();

noti.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.notify(0, noti);
```

Assuming that my sound stored like that : (\assets\hopo.mp3)

how to make this notification pushed with this sound without changing the push notification systems for other apps by changing the sound from the list that android device offered !!.

I hope my question is very clear to you :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15809399/android-notification-sound

Comment: Try to put your sound file on raw directories under res and set sound to notification like : notification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" +R.raw.hopo);

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335057/play-notification-default-sound-only-android

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android GCM PushNotification - Add add custom sound file in app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24731591/android-gcm-pushnotification-add-add-custom-sound-file-in-app)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To combine the answers here and using the two answers from these questions:

- [How to add sound to notification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14043977/how-to-add-sound-to-notification)
- [How to get URI from an asset File?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820816/how-to-get-uri-from-an-asset-file)

Try this:

```
Uri sound = Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/hopo.mp3");

Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(MainActivity.this)
    .setTicker("Calcupital")
    .setContentTitle("Calcupital")
    .setContentText("User Information has been updated successfully")
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.login)

    .setSound(sound);

    .setContentIntent(pIntent).getNotification();

noti.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.notify(0, noti);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set default sound using

```
Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
if (alarmSound != null) {
    mBuilder.setSound(alarmSound);
}
```

if you want custom sound just use different `Uri`. how to get `Uri` from assets? [check this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820816/how-to-get-uri-from-an-asset-file)

Answer (score 0):

You need to place your sound file to res/raw directory.

Then add this code into current code

```
final String packageName = context.getPackageName();
notification.sound =
Uri.parse("android.resource://" + packageName + "R.raw.hopo");
```

see this link for more details 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setSound(android.net.Uri)

Comment: Do you know how to do the same on API 26?

Answer (score 0):

To get the resource:

```
Uri alarmSound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + this.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.somefile);
```

** the raw folder must be created inside res folder and add youre sound file **

To set up:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder noBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
           .setContentText(message)
           .setSound(alarmSound) // -> add this one
           .setVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000 });
```